# Automated testing whith parallel users and captha in login (with selenium webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, automated-tests

**What I need to do**
is write automated test which tests whether or not web system works enough fast. (steps are not longer than 1s). and there should be ~100 parallel system users.

To achieve the goal, I use Selenium Webdriver and I learned how to write simple tests (in Java) but there are 2 main problems:

> 1) How can I add parallel users? If I create 100 instances then PC will crash. I read something about selenium grid and TestNG but still not convinced what I really need.
>
> 2) There is a captcha in login page. I suppose there are better solution for sleeping all threads while I'm making manual login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe you need a performance test tool instead of a browser automation tool like webdriver.
   As such, Grid and testng can help you with parallel tests, I would say they would be tools to fasten your functional tests and not for performance tests.
2. Captcha - The whole idea of introducing captcha is that it should prevent the flow from being automated.  Manually entering captcha in the 100 instances would defeat the purpose of automation. In most orgs, people give a fixed code in testing environments to bypass the captcha.  You can talk with your dev team to figure out options.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Spoke with developers and they advised to use ab Apache Bench for performance tests and now I don't have captha problem! :)